# aspectj annotation not working with flink

Tags: spring, apache-flink, aspectj

I have created a custom annotation to log time consumed by a method using aspectj library and spring.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyMethodPerformance {
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyMethodPerformanceAspect {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMethodPerformanceAspect.class);

    public MyMethodPerformanceAspect() {
    }

    @Around("@annotation(MyMethodPerformance)")
    public Object logMethodPerfomance(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object var6;
        try {
            Long methodStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
            Long methodEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
            MDC.put("methodName", signature.getMethod().getName());
            MDC.put("className", signature.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName());
            MDC.put("duration", Long.toString(methodEndTime - methodStartTime));
            LOGGER.info("Method performance");
            var6 = proceed;
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }

        return var6;
    }
}
```

I tested it in a spring boot application for one of the rest endpoint and it works fine.

But when I annotate map method in my flink job class, it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you are missing is that Spring AOP only works for Spring-managed beans/components, not for non-Spring POJOs. For that you need full AspectJ, not an "AOP lite" framework like Spring AOP.

Comment: So I made flink class a spring bean(added @Component). But still annotation doesn't work.

Comment: In that case and if you are sure that the component scan actually picks up your new component, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. If you have a Git repository to clone for me, I can take a look.